# Azure: Cannot ping/telnet the MS Sql Database via Cloud Service - Remote Desktop

Tags: sql-server, azure, remote-desktop, azure-cloud-services

I've set up a new Cloud Service in MS Azure. When I try to connect to the database, it appears an "SqlException: Network-related or instance-specific error ... Error 40: Could not open a connection to SQL Server".

This account has already set up some Cloud Services that are able to connect to the same database, but the new one I just uploaded cannot. I checked all the configurations and I can't find the solution.

In addition, I connected to the Cloud Service - Remote Desktop and I typed 
telnet  1433 
in order to check the connection but it fails.

Any ideas will be helpful! Thanks

Comment: Is the database on a VM in the same cloud service as the VM you just created? If so, how are you addressing the SQL host?  If not, is 1433 declared as an input endpoint in the cloud service where the SQL host is located and does it have an ACL on it that could be blocking requests from the new VMs cloud service?

Comment: As far as I know, I had to be able to ping the database through the Remote Desktop of the Cloud Service. Unfortunately, this is not successful. Any ideas of configurations I have to do in order to succeed that?

Comment: Try the same from one of the existing (working) Cloud Services. I think that `ping` won't return an answer because of azure blocking that.

Comment: In particular, I tried
telnet <databasename> 1433
and it works for existing Cloud Services, but not for the new one.

Comment: Its important to understand where the new VM is... if its not in the same cloud service as the previously existing VMs that work... then the issue may be that the SQL Database does not have an input endpoint declared for port 1433. Cloud Services represent a network isolation boundary and machines are not addressable across those boundaries unless they are within a Virtual Network.